# How to install Mono 4.0.1 on Debian 8?

Tags: linux, mono, debian

I am attempting to install Mono-Complete onto a fresh brand new installation of Debian 8 in order to use ASP.NET 5 as per (code.visualstudio.com/docs), have followed the mono-project.com documentation for Ubuntu 12.04/Debian 8 or later with regards to the second repository that is needed.

However, after following the instructions and attempting to do 'apt-get install mono-complete' I end up with the following issue: http://puu.sh/hxdLB/dbecbf9645.png

This is on a 100% fresh Debian 8 VM (Virtualbox), just finished installing Debian 8 NetInst + Cinnamon, logged into the system as root and added the 2 repos.

If I try and manually install one of those dependencies (such as mono-devel) it comes up with an even bigger list of unmet dependencies that won't be installed.

Comment: Same situation on a non-clean Debian Jessie. Have apt-get install and remove(d) mono and wine previously. Aiming to test some previously non-compatible software with mono 4.0.1... no joy as of yet.

Comment: A friend suggested to me to comment out the 2 mono-project repos, do an apt-get update, then install mono-complete, uncomment those 2 repos, apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, then apt-get install mono-devel. Seems like it is working so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an issue with the Mono packages that should now be resolved, please see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#libgdiplus-debian-80-and-later-not-ubuntu.

The reason is that Debian 8 doesn't have libjpeg8 anymore which libgdiplus (a component of Mono) requires.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I added all 3 repositories, and I still get the same error.

Comment: You will need to run `sudo apt-get update` after adding it. Worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this by following article posted by **Alexander** but also installed one more package `monodevelop`.

Following commands i run to install **mod mono** on debian 8.0 jessie:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libjpeg62-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

To get development IDE run:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

After then can successfully run : `sudo a2enmod mod_mono_auto`