# MSBUILD with mono on jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, msbuild, mono

I want to set a continuous integration environment on my raspberry in order to build and deploy Xamarin.Android and other .Net projects.

I installed Jenkins on my raspbian.
I installed Mono on my server following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982959/how-to-install-mono-4-0-1-on-debian-8).

I'm able to run a `xbuild`command : 
[image]

I installed the [MSBUILD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin) on Jenkins.

I face trouble trying to configure Jenkins with MSBUILD command.
In the system configuration, I have the following snapshot : 
[image]

I do not know what is the path to MSBUILD I have to set. I do not know how to get it from my server. I'm sure the mono instalation worked fine because I can use MSBUILD in command line. How can I retrieve this information ?

On Windows it would be this path : `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\{version}\MSBuild.exe`
On Mac it would be something like that : `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the path following [this article](http://blog.bekijkhet.com/2013/01/create-mono-c-buildserver-using-jenkins.html)

```
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xbuild.exe
```